# Dual boot win 10 ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I do not have the option to install Ubuntu along side windows 10.

It only gives the option to format the drive, and install Ubuntu.

However I have partitioned my drive to make space for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thx Dugi. Im new to ubuntu. Will have a look and c what I can figure out lol.

Comment: If system originally Windows 10, then you may still have fast start up on? Or if originally Windows 7 you may have that plus the BIOS/MBR 4 primary partition limit. Assuming UEFI/gpt. Also shows Windows 8 screens or similar to Windows 10
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system and:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option to do *something else*, at the bottom of the window. If you pick that one, it will let you pick the partition you want to use for Ubuntu, which ones do you want to format and which you don't, pretty much anything you might possibly want.